# Architecture of an updatable class with non-updatable base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, architecture

I have the following situation:

- I have a base read-only class with simple information
- I have a second class that inherits from the base class, this class' members can be updated

  public class ExtendedClass : BaseClass
  {}
- To check if a class can be updated I have an abstract class UpdatableRecord
- This abstract class has a property RecordState ("Deleted", "Edited", "New", "None")
- this property has the default value "deleted".

What is the best way to build the classes (use different interfaces?, how is the hierarchy?)

Comment: What kind of information does the BaseClass have? Who wants to check if a class is "updatable" and what for?

Comment: The BaseClass have only simple informations like an ID or a description. The extendedClass have also different flags for settings (example: IsAdmin). 
the updatable is checked on the server-site in the BL. I want to have this different classes because some UI views are only for display and there don't need the settings flags.

Comment: Seems like those classes are not going to follow SRP. I think you should rethink your design. I can'y say more as the description is a little vague and chaotic.

Comment: What do you mean with chaotic? Maybe I can explain it a little bit better.

Comment: What's the broader context? Use some code samples. The one you posted gives no useful information.

Comment: you should build the classes using Visual Studio

Comment: You ask us: How can I repair my car? And all you say is that it has some moving parts, 4 wheels and it's blue.